# access a external service running on a vm form inside kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cluster in aws and using kubernetes.
I have an app running on a machine (vm) in the same network as the cluster
in my browser i can type http://ipaddress:port/status and i get a response

In my pod i can ping the ip address and i get a response but if i do wget://ipaddress:port/status it doesn't connect.

I have tried some things but not able to succeed.
How do i get the pod in the cluster to be be able to open this url, what do I need to do?

Comment: Is the ipaddress an external one? Where's this VM running?

Comment: The vm is on the same network and there is a nodejs app running that i want the cluster to have access to.The cluster is in aws and i can access it from my local machine. on my local machine I can access both the cluster and the nodejs app. On my local machine I can do a wget and I get a response

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate external services within kubernetes.

endpoint.yaml

```
    kind: Endpoints
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: external-ip-database
    subsets:
      - addresses:
        - ip: 192.168.0.1
        ports:
    - port: 3306
```

service.yaml

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: database
    spec:
      ports:
      - port: 1433
        targetPort: 1433
        protocol: TCP
    ---
    # Because this service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoints
    # object will not be created. You can manually map the service to
    # your own specific endpoints:
    kind: Endpoints
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: database
    subsets:
      - addresses:
          - ip: "192.168.1.103"
        ports:
          - port: 1433
```

Comment: Hi Pamir, thanks for sending me the example. in the example you sent me are you creating 2 services.In your example is the database running inside the cluster with the ip address 192.168.1.1.03 and port number 3306. i my scenario the database(actually nodejs) is sitting on a seperate vm.

Comment: Hi Anita,
In this scenario your are internalizing an external service. You can get more information from the link below.

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html

Comment: Thanks for sending me the link . It looks straightforward. I am looking into it though i was not sure how to check that the service is available in the pod. do i just go inside the pod and type telnet 192.68.01 1433 and it should come back with a response

Comment: If i understand you correctly,  you should resolve by name and connect from 1433 port. I should record a video to you

Comment: Hello, am new to Kubernetes. Am wondering how to consume the service. In my case am using typescript mongoose to connect to my MongoDB server